# Including underscore template IN my jQuery/js

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

I have read probably all of the posts about underscore and templates, but can't seem to achieve something simple. I can't have the template in a `<script>` tag inline in my html. I just want to declare the template with the js script that gets data from an API.

I want to put this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="eventView">
    <div class="table-tour">
        <% _.each(collection, function( model, id ) { %>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell date"><% var monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
            var str = model.datetime;  
            var dateArr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("T")).split("-");                    
            var month = parseInt(dateArr[1],10);
            var day = parseInt(dateArr[2],10);
            print(monthNames[month-1] + " " + day); %></div>
            <div class="cell location"><%= model.formatted_location %></div>
            <div class="cell venue"><%= model.venue.name %></div>
            <div class="cell actions"><% if (model.ticket_status == "available") { %>
            <span><a href="<%= model.ticket_url %>" target="_blank">Tickets</a></span> <% } %>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
</script>
```

In here:

```
// Display all dates:
var content;
if (data.length > 0)
    content = _.template( $( "script#eventView" ).html(), { "collection": data } );
else
{
    var notifyUrl = "http://www.bandsintown.com/" + artistName;
    content = "<p class='notify'>No " + mode + " dates. <a href='" + notifyUrl + "' target='_blank'>Notify me when " + artistName + " comes to my area.</a></p>";
}

$("#tour-dates").html(content);
```

I keep trying to add it into:

`_.template( $( "script#eventView" ).html(), { "collection": data } );`

but failing.

Wondering if someone has a tip.

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of Underscore? What specifically does "failing" mean?

Comment: It's v 1.4.4. Sorry, "failing" as in I can't recreate the template within that js if statement.

Comment: You want the template in a JavaScript string instead of a `<script>`?

Comment: Exactly. I was also exploring a `get()` method but if I could just declare my template right here it would be ideal: `_.template( $( "script#eventView" ).html(), { "collection": data } );`

Comment: So what is stopping you from saying `var s = '<div class="table-tour">...'; _.template(s, ...)`? Or using a `$.get` and dealing with the template in its callback?

Answer (score 0):

You mean to store ejs(or some custom) template in your html. You can not do that directly. As when browser would be trying to parse, it will not recognize its format, as it does not support ejs(or any custom templating) format. You can have its escape value stored in javascript variable or data attribute. But I wouldn't recommend that for readability sake.

You should probably make ajax call for that in javascript to fetch that template. If you want that to be prefetched then just make ajax call in in script tag to fetch that and store that template some where in javascript variable.

You may use http://www.embeddedjs.com/ plugin for convenience if that template language is ejs.